# how to use AWS SAM on NodeJs Lambda by Gitlab-ci?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

**My gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
build_aws_sam:
  image: python:3.11
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
  script:
    - sam build --config-env "dev"
```

**Error:**

```
Building codeuri: /builds/xxxx-aws/xxxx-application/serverless/src/populateDynamo runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: ServerlessDynamoStack/PopulateDynamoFunction
package.json file not found. Continuing the build without dependencies.
Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmBuilder:Resolver - Path resolution for runtime: nodejs18.x of binary: npm was not successful
```

I try add this in `before_script` but same error:

```
    - pip3 install nodejs-bin --upgrade
    - pip3 install npm --upgrade
```

I read AWS official documentation for `aws-sam-cli` and we need use Python image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution work for me: `- apt-get install nodejs -yq` but after a `curl` on `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x`

**full gitlab-ci file:**

```
build_aws_sam:
  image: python:3.11
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
    - apt-get update -y
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash
    - apt-get install nodejs -yq
  script:
    - sam build --config-env "dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the prebuilt AWS SAM images can be used. For Node.js:

```
Node.js 20  public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs20.x
Node.js 18  public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs18.x
Node.js 16  public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs16.x
Node.js 14  public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x
Node.js 12  public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs12.x
```

All images can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-image-repositories.html#serverless-image-repository-uris

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` will look like this:

```
build_aws_sam:
  image: public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs20.x
  stage: build
  script:
    - sam build
    - sam deploy
```

The Dockerfiles for the AWS SAM images above can be found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-build-images/tree/develop/build-image-src

Comment: in my sample, I need use Python image because I use Python AWS lambda and NodeJs lambda.

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON for Python Lambdas you can use the Python images and for Node.js Lambdas the Node.js images. if you prefer to use the same image for both Python and Node.js, the Node.js 20 image has Python 3.9.16, since it needs it for the sam-cli. but I wouldn't recommend to use the same image, they should be separate.

Comment: you have not understood, I have Python lambdas and NodeJs lambdas in the same project so in the same SAM so also in the same deploy by SAM. If I do in two images, this is already not practical because I will have to cut my lambda into two groups for the build but in addition I will have to deploy in two times which is not good at all.